# Send message from web page to chrome extension

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-typescript

I want to be able to send a message from my web app to my chrome extension so it can easier to use (send the auth token so users dont have to login twice). However after looking at the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage) and reading a bunch of SO questions, I cannot get anything working for me.

Here's some parts my `manifest.json`:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://330218550995.ngrok.io; object-src 'self'",
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
"externally_connectable": {
    "matches": [
        "*://localhost/*",
        "*://*.ngrok.io/*"
    ]
},
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
    "exclude_matches": [
      "*://*.olympiatasks.com/*",
      "https://app.olympiatasks.com/*",
      "https://*.olympiatasks.com/*"
  ],
    "css": ["/static/css/main.css"],
    "js": [
      "/static/js/runtime-main.js", 
      "/static/js/2.js", 
      "/static/js/main.js"
    ]
  }
],
```

Inside of the `content script` I do this:

```
const ExtensionID = process.env.REACT_APP_EXTENSION_ID || '';
chrome?.runtime.connect(ExtensionID, { name: 'example' });
chrome?.runtime?.sendMessage('Hi from content script')
```

Inside of the `web page` I do this:

```
const ExtensionID = process.env.REACT_APP_EXTENSION_ID || "";
chrome.runtime.connect(ExtensionID, { name: "example" });
chrome?.runtime?.sendMessage(ExtensionID, "Hi from app");
```

Then here is the listener in the `background.js`:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log({ request })
});

chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
    console.log("Received message from " + sender + ": ", request);
    sendResponse({ received: true }); //respond however you like
});
```

When I open the website, the extension is successfully injected and in the dev console of the `background.js` page I get the following:

> Hello world from background.js
>
> {request: "Hi from content script"}

The "hi from app" is missing which means it's not being sent/received. I used `ngrok` to setup forwarding to my app thinking that either:

- The domain being `localhost`
- The protocol not being `https`

could be the problem but as you guess, no luck.

So far I have done the following:

- Setup my `externally_connectable` inside my `manifest.json`
- Setup the `onMessageExternal` listener in the `background.js`
- Call `runtime.sendMessage` with the Extension ID like shown [in the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage)
- Used an `https` website for secure connection

Any help on this issue is greatly appreciated

Comment: Tentatively, since ngrok.io is in [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat) it means it's basically like `com` which is forbidden in externally_connectable. Try using a more specific pattern for the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @wOxxOm comment I was able to resolve the issue.

I quote:

> Tentatively, since ngrok.io is in [public suffix list](https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat) it means it's basically like com which is forbidden in externally_connectable. Try using a more specific pattern for the site.

I changed the URL to use one more specific `https://330218550995.ngrok.io/*` and it now works

Answer (score -1):

We can synchronize the authentication token between the website and chrome extension using content-script and background js file.

> Inside `web page` I do this
> ...

I am not sure how you did it on the `web page`

Here is what I did to send access token from `web page` to `extension`.

Here is my `content-script` file.

```
/* eslint-disable no-undef */

const hostScript = () => {
  // ----------------- Function Declarations -----------------

  let listenGetTokenResponseFromWindow = () => {};

  const sendMessagesToExtension = (msg, callback = null) => {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(msg);
  };

  const sendMessagesToWindow = (msg, callback = null) => {
    const { type } = msg;
    
    switch (type) {
      case ExtensionMessagesTypes.GetTokenFromWindow:
        // Can not pass the function with window.postMessage. Only JSON object can be passed.
        // So reset the listener
        window.postMessage(msg, document.location.origin);

        window.removeEventListener("message", listenGetTokenResponseFromWindow);
        listenGetTokenResponseFromWindow = event => {
          if (event.source !== window) return;
          if (event.data.type === ExtensionMessagesTypes.GetTokenFromWindowResponse) {
            const { payload } = event.data;
            !!callback && callback(payload.token);
          }
        };
        window.addEventListener("message", listenGetTokenResponseFromWindow);
        break;
      case ExtensionMessagesTypes.SetWindowToken:
        window.postMessage(msg, document.location.origin);
        !!callback && callback();
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  const listenMessagesFromWindow = event => {
    if (event.source !== window) return;

    const msg = event.data;
    
    Object.values(ExtensionMessagesTypes).includes(msg.type) && sendMessagesToExtension(msg);
  };

  const listenMessagesFromExtension = (msg, sender, response) => {
    sendMessagesToWindow(msg, response);
    return true; // means response is async
  };

  // ----------------- Listener Definitions -----------------

  window.removeEventListener("message", listenMessagesFromWindow);
  window.addEventListener("message", listenMessagesFromWindow);

  chrome.runtime.onMessage.removeListener(listenMessagesFromExtension);
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(listenMessagesFromExtension);

  // Reset extension token as windows token
  sendMessagesToWindow({ type: ExtensionMessagesTypes.GetTokenFromWindow }, token => {
    sendMessagesToExtension({
      type: ExtensionMessagesTypes.SetExtensionToken,
      payload: { token }
    });
  });
};
```

Here is the `background.js` file.

```
(() => {
        chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, response) => {
            switch (msg.type) {
                case ExtensionMessagesTypes.GetTokens:
                    getAccessTokens(response);
                    break;
                case ExtensionMessagesTypes.SetExtensionToken:
                    !!msg.payload && !!msg.payload.token && setAccessTokenToExtensionLocalStorage(msg.payload.token, response);
                    break;
                case ExtensionMessagesTypes.SetWindowToken:
                    !!msg.payload && !!msg.payload.token && sendMessageFromExtensionToWindow(msg, response);
                    break;
            }
    });
})();

const sendMessageFromExtensionToWindow = (msg, callback = null) => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, url: `${HostURL}/*` }, tabs => {
        if (tabs.length < 1) {
            !!callback && callback(null);
            return;
        }

        if (msg.type === ExtensionMessagesTypes.GetTokenFromWindow) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, msg, token => {
                !!callback && callback(token);
            });
        } else if (msg.type === ExtensionMessagesTypes.SetWindowToken) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, msg, () => {
                !!callback && callback();
            });
        }
    });
};

// Authentication

const setAccessTokenToExtensionLocalStorage = (access_token, callback = null) => {
    chrome.storage.local.set({ access_token }, () => {
        !!callback && callback();
    });
};

const getAccessTokenFromChromeStorage = callback => {
    chrome.storage.local.get(['access_token'], result => {
        !!callback && callback(result.access_token);
    });
};

const getAccessTokens = callback => {
    getAccessTokenFromChromeStorage(accessTokenFromExtension => {
        sendMessageFromExtensionToWindow({ type: ExtensionMessagesTypes.GetTokenFromWindow }, accessTokenFromWindow => {
            callback({
                accessTokenFromExtension: accessTokenFromExtension || '',
                accessTokenFromWindow: accessTokenFromWindow || ''
            });
        });
    });
};

const handleLogin = payload => {
    //TODO: Handling refresh token
    
    const { token } = payload;
    if (!token) return;

    setAccessTokenToExtensionLocalStorage(token);
};

const handleLogout = () => {
    setAccessTokenToExtensionLocalStorage(null);
};
```

PS: You don't need `externally_connectable` option in the manifest.json file.

Comment: This answers is for communicating between the `content script` and the `background script` but my JWT tokens is coming from a web app and I want to send from my web app to the `background script`

Comment: @FrenchMajesty I think it answers to both questions. That `window.postMessage` doesn't send data to background script. Or does it?